# Pushing a new object to a nested array in Mongoose in async functions

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await

Let's say I have a Schema that looks like this:

```
const Schema1 = new Schema({
  field1: String,
  field2: String,
  array1: [{
    objfield1: String
    objfield2: Date,
    objfield3: {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'OtherModel',
      required: true,
    },
  }],
}, options);
```

Here `array1` is an array of objects. I want to be able to hit an endpoint with a PUT request and push a new object into the `array1` array. I have tried using _.merge from lodash, I have tried using `push` to add the new object into the array, but to no avail.

```
exports.addObject = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    let schemaInstance = await db.Schema1.findById(req.params.id);
    schemaInstance['array1'].push(req.body)
    schemaInstance.markModified('array1');
    let updatedSchemaInstance = await schemaInstance.save();

    return res.status('200').json(updatedSchemaInstance);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message: 'No users in the database',
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: do you get any err from the try..catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want update your array with new element, use `findOneAndUpdate()` function and `$push`

like:

```
exports.addObject = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    let schemaInstance = await db.Schema1.findOneAndUpdate(
      {_id: req.params.id}, 
      {$push: {'array1': req.body});
    schemaInstance.markModified('array1');
    let updatedSchemaInstance = await schemaInstance.save();

    return res.status('200').json(updatedSchemaInstance);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return next({
      status: 400,
      message: 'No users in the database',
    });
  }
};
```

mongoose `findOneAndUpdate()` : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate
mongo `$push` : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: Thanks! This worked, with the caveat that the option {new: true} is needed to return the updated record.